# Ignore synced folder files/directories with NFS as sync system for Vagrant

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, rsync, nfs, smb

Is there any way to make [NFS](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/synced-folders/nfs.html) to ignore specified files and/or directories from the synced folder? I have done it with `rsync` ([rsync__exclude](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/synced-folders/rsync.html)), but don't find any reference for NFS. I'm also looking for a solution for [SMB](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/synced-folders/smb.html). Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In my case I had to keep cache and log files unsynchronized, and the solution I found out was to create a symbolic link instead of the cache and log folders (e.g. `app/cache` and `app/log`) which points to a directory outside the synchronized folder (e.g. `/home/vagrant/project/cache`). Then, the files inside `app/cache` are not synchronized. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 4):

My rep isn't high enough to comment on the above answer, I had the exact same problem. I had to do a little work and figure this detail out:

The symlink must be in your virtual machine. So for example:

```
vagrant ssh
cd your/webapp
mkdir outside/your/webapp
ln -s outside/your/webapp cache
```

Now the symlink will show up in your project folder, but you won't actually be synchronizing any files across it.

Comment: Of course, `/home/vagrant/project/cache` is outside the sync folder, but inside the VM.

Comment: Maybe it will be a good point to say that in this case `outsite/folder` needs additional file permissions.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to combine NFS and RSync. In the RSync we can **exclude the NFS folders**

This is what I have in my vagrantfile for a Symfony 3.4 project. Every folder will be NFS except the **/var** folder

```
biDirectionalNFSFolders = []

Dir.foreach('.') do |folder|

    # Skip if not a directory?
    # Skip if /var folder
    # Skip if . or .. folder
    next if !File.directory?(folder) or folder == 'var' or folder == '.' or folder == '..'

    # This folder can be NFS synced
    fullPath = '/htdocs/' + folder
    biDirectionalNFSFolders.push(fullPath)
    config.vm.synced_folder "." + fullPath, "/vagrant" + fullPath, type: "nfs", mount_options: ['rw', 'vers=3', 'tcp', 'fsc', 'nolock', 'actimeo=2']

end

# The remaining folders (/var only in this case) can then be Rsynced, the NFS folders will be excluded
config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", type: "rsync",
    rsync__exclude: biDirectionalNFSFolders
```